# SSL handshake duration / time benchmark without body

Tags: webserver, benchmarking, haproxy, apachebench

is there any way to benchmark SSL handshake time?
I want to know how much ssl handshakes my server can handle but i dont want the body of the website.
I tried ApacheBench and Vegeta but i think these tools are not the right thing.